# How to bind Gridview update with Object Datasource parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview for a shopping cart with columns

```
id | productName | productPrice | productQuantity | totalPrice
```

Quantity is the only editable column in gridview. I need to pass the id and the quantity to the datasource , how can i do that? I am a beginner and  have been working on it for an hour now and a help would be appreciated

**.aspx file**

```
   <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="getListFromCart" TypeName="GetFromCart" DeleteMethod="deleteListFromCart" UpdateMethod="updateListFromCart"  >
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="quantity" Type="Int32" />

        </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="2" >
        <Columns>

            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="productName" HeaderText="productName" SortExpression="productName" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="productPrice" HeaderText="productPrice" SortExpression="productPrice" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="quantity" SortExpression="quantity">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="totalPrice" HeaderText="totalPrice" SortExpression="totalPrice"  ReadOnly="True" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

**.cs file**

```
public static void updateListFromCart(int id,int quantity)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("updateCartDetails", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = quantity;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to provide more information than just stating that you have been working on this for more than `1` hour.. what issues errors or anomalies are you experiencing..?

Comment: this is close to working.  you might have to call gridview.databind() to see the results updated.  (BTW, you don't need to call conn.Close(), using will take care of that for you.